# Flex : securityError while trying to reverse geocode with google api?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

```
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            Security.allowDomain("*.googleapis.com" );
            Security.allowDomain("*.google.com" );

            var q : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                q.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onGeocodingComplete );
                q.load( new URLRequest( 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.548555,24.558466&sensor=false' ) );


        }

        protected function onGeocodingComplete( event : Event ) : void
        {
            Alert.show( 'geocoding succeed' );
        }
```

I try with the code above, but it throw me :

```
sandbox violationError #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation...
```

- how can I directly access reverse geocoding services trought Flash?

  *because the geocoder with Flash API doesnt providing sufficient data.*

Comment: You could use JavaScript to do the geocoding stuff and pass the data to flash using ExternalInterface

Comment: nah. the main idea is to be far away from Javascript. - Javascript in my case is like : "Avoid Javascript by all means possible" :D ( anyway it is good idea maybe for other peoples )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Geocoder class listed in Google Maps API for Flash.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/reference#ClientGeocoder

Answer (score 1):

create new php page **mypage.php**

```
<?php
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.548555,24.558466&sensor=false");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
?>
```

flash:

```
q.load(new URLRequest("mypage.php"));
```

Comment: it is good idea, but no server side queries toward the server be performed. anyway it is good idea aswell :)